# Site violates Google's quality guidelines - Can't figure out why

Tags: google, seo, pagerank

I am at a loss!
Our website has been delisted due to "Site violates Google's quality guidelines" and "We've reviewed your site and we still see links to your site that violate our quality guidelines. Specifically, look for possibly artificial or unnatural links pointing to your site that could be intended to manipulate PageRank.".

After months of cleaning up backlinks and jumping through hoops, we re-submitted and have yet again been knocked back.

HOW can I identify which links Google is penalising us for?
Is there some sort of tool that can provide hints as to which links I should review?

Comment: I'm sure there are better answers to come, but doing a google search for `linkto:www.cyberdesignworks.com.au/` is helpful...and you seem to have been blacklisted by some whois provider as well: http://www.check-tools.com/domains/c/cyberdesignworks.com.au.html

Answer (score 2):

There are many sites that will show you your backlinks (including google), [**opensiteexplorer**](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/) is one of them and [**Alexa**](http://www.alexa.com/) is another one I like using. 
A website that'll help you locate and remove suspicious backlinks: **[removeem](http://www.removeem.com/)**, and a free tool:  [**NetPeak Checker**](http://net-peak.com/software/netpeak-checker/).

Sometimes it's easier to "start fresh" and buy a new domain. Whatever you do, don't use [blackhat SEO techniques](http://www.designhammer.com/blog/17-black-hat-seo-techniques-avoid) and don't use SEO services of someone you cannot trust in regards - [*the price is too high*](http://news.softpedia.com/news/J-C-Penney-Caught-Using-Black-Hat-SEO-184307.shtml), as you can now see.

Comment: _the price is too high, as you can now see._ As one of our competitors found out, 6 months to selling of company. Muck with the search engines, get banned, try to make up for it with print advertizing = massive reduction in profits and bankruptcy. And we didn't have to do a thing, the wound was totally self inflicted. Three weeks in SERP positions 1 to 3 doesn't make up for the time period you're banned.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem, if you go to Google Webmaster Tools and click on the account that you are having problems with you can click on **traffic** link that is in the side navigation, then click on **links to your site** that is under the traffic link, under the heading **Your most linked content** there will be a list of URL's under there is a **more** link, then under the overview there are 3 buttons if you click **Download Latest Links** button you can obtain a CSV with all the latest links (back to 2008 in my case), if you check this with the date you received the message from Google you will have a start on where to look for unnatural links.
hope it helps